# How do I make a Stronghold locater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to make a stronghold finder using TNT and redstone, but I don't know how. Every time I try it out I end up blowing myself up. This is my current design:

[image]

Comment: You can make a screenshot with F2 on PC (will save in .minecraft\screenshots folder). On xbox I think you can do it somehow with Y, but I don't know the details.

Comment: You should be able to use glowstone instead of TNT. That would be much safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really simple to do:
Remove all redstone and put the lever next to the top piston, diagonally from the TNT. It will power both pistons. This has the downside that the lever will be visible when the pistons are extended and will take some of your view space. Here is a more complex design that doesn't suffer from that limitation: [image: better design]

Comment: I don't understand how this could be used to locate Strongholds, and a quick web search didn't point me anywhere. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @blubb This is a trick that allows you to see underground. It relies on the odd fact that TNT does not suffocate you. The hole is two blocks deep and two pistons push two blocks of TNT onto your character and you end up inside the TNT blocks. I have used this to see unlit caves underground, so I can explore them, mrminecraft3000 apparently wants to use it to locate the exact position of a stronghold, once he is in its immediate vicinity.

Comment: Note that the glitch works exactly the same with glowstone instead of TNT, except WITHOUT the risk of blowing yourself up.

Comment: First i need to find some glowstone then. And that is indeed the case that i want to find a stronghold or a abanded mineshaft. Whichever i see first.